# In spectroscopy, what element does green indicate presence of in the atmosphere?

Tags: visible-light, atmospheric-science, physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, meteorology

And what element does visible green glow indicate in our own atmosphere?
https://youtu.be/HDlsdVuv6qQ

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided is to the green glow of a meteor or possible space junk falling over Australia.  In that case, the color is probably due to the composition of the falling object rather than to the composition of the atmosphere.  There are lots of substances that produce green light when they are heated enough: copper and nickel are a couple of examples.  It's very likely that those metals are components of the object.

Atmospheric glow, on the other hand, would be due to components of the atmosphere.  Oxygen is one possible candidate, referenced in [this article](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/green-glow-detected-mars-atmosphere-180975113/).